# Bootstrap display flex height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I want to make my navigation list from bootstrap in the same height as the navbar itself.

Current html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Which comes out like this:

[image]

I want to make it look like this:

[image]

I currently fixed it by giving the `div.collapse` a fix height of 60 pixels and `ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto`, `li.nav-item` and `a.nav-link` a height of 100%. The problem is that this is only a workaround and will not work for mobile devices etc.

By checking out the css I recognized that bootstrap is now using a method called `flex`. How can I make that possible using flex?

Comment: can you add snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to leave the default height then removing the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` from the parent ( `nav-bar` ) and adding them to the children ( `nav-link` ) will do the trick,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .nav-link {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

if you fix the `height` of the `nav-bar` then why not just fix the `height` of the `children` ?

```
.nav-bar{
    height: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .nav-link {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

another option is to set the position of the `parent` ( `nav-bar` ) to `relative` and the `position` of the children to `absolute` and `height:100%` with `top:0`

```
.nav-bar{ 
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .nav-link {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/szuk7not/62/

PS : for your future questions, please consider adding a snippet, codePen, fiddle or at least working `html` and `css` so you can get more precise and adequate answers.